# Capture picture using front camera without user knows

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to capture picture through front camera without user knows that he was captured when authentication failed..Can anybody suggest me how to do?

Thanks,
Chaitanya.K

Comment: Are you planning to tell the user that the app can do such a thing? If so, I won't install your app. If not, people will probably sue you.

Comment: I won't tell the user that you have captured when login failed.I want to use it for security purpose

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only do such a thing if the owner of the phone (which is not necessarily the same as the user) knows about it. Otherwise, you'll definitely run into legal and privacy issues.

Comment: I willl definitely inform to the owner of the phone that I am going to capture the image when some one trying to open the application.Finally I got the solution for that ...:-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

not sure but can try

this code is [Android: take a picture without displaying a preview](http://www.41post.com/3794/programming/android-take-a-picture-without-displaying-a-preview)

so you can to put what you want to show preview screen like show the message and say user to press ok or any other better option to say the user to press button and onpress capture the image .........

Comment: Thanks for reply I have tried with.It didn't meet my requirement.When I set the surface width ,surface height as zero dip.then it didn't capture the image but when it sets to match_parent It vl capturing.but at that time user knew that he was captured.But i dnt want to give any clue.The Vault Application people have done.I don't know how those people worked

Comment: gr8..........well done...... if possible can you tell what you did finally .........

Comment: As u referred the example in that I have just changed my surface view width and height as match_parent..That's it ...:-)