# Getting input from camera without displaying it

Tags: android, iphone, ios, camera

I'm a newbie. My question is is relevant for both IOS and Android.

1. Say I want to analyze what camera sees in real time, is it possible to get video stream from camera online?
2. Is it possible that when camera is streaming data to application, phone display won't show what camera sees, but rather some application related information?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a Research Assistant.

Comment: Sounds like spying on the user, If you ask me. Kind of black hat...

Comment: @ranReloaded Maybe there are already watching us!? :) Actually it's not  about "spying".

Comment: All right, but in any case, my advice would be: make sure the user is aware of the functionality.

Comment: @ranReloaded You're right, of course.

Comment: not exactly what you want but takr a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027246/capture-picture-using-front-camera-without-user-knows/11027614#11027614

Answer (score 2):

> Say I want to analyze what camera sees in real time, is it possible to
>   get video stream from camera online?

yes, both platforms have Video conference applications, so this must be possible.

> Is it possible that when camera is streaming data to application,
>   phone display won't show what camera sees, but rather some application
>   related information?

No idea about iOS, but on Android I think it should be possible. Follow along in the [Developer docs for recording video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) But leave out the preview layout. 
Note: I haven't tried this but I see no reason on the surface that it wouldn't work.